# How to create multiline lists from raw file and process them in python?

Tags: python, list, file, multiline

I have the following code that takes `raw_file.txt` and turns it into `processed_file.txt`.

**Problem 1:**

Besides `item_location` I also need the `item_id` (as str, not int) to be in the processed file, perhaps as list so it would look like `WANTED_processed_file.txt`

```
def process_file(raw_file, processed_file, target1):
    with open(raw_file, 'r') as raw_file:
        with open(processed_file, 'a') as processed_file:
            for line in raw_file:
                if target1 in line:
                    processed_file.write(line.split(target1)[1])

process_file('raw_file.txt', 'processed_file.txt', 'item_location: ')
```

By adding another if statement with `target2`, the content is appended below `target1` (as expected), but I don't actually know how to make it a list.

**Problem 2:**

With my current code I'm only able to process the string corresponding to the line, but since `WANTED_processed_file.txt` contains multiple list I need to adapt it.

```
def my_function():
    print(i)

with open('processed_file.txt', "r") as processed_file:
    items = processed_file.read().splitlines()
    for i in items:
        my_function()
```

This is what I've tried but I'm not getting the desired results:

```
def my_function():
    print(f'Item {i[0]} is located at {i[1]}')

with open('WANTED_processed_file.txt', "r") as processed_file:
    items = processed_file.read()
    for i in items:
        my_function()
```

raw_file.txt:

```
ITEM:
item_id: 0001
item_location: first location
item_description: something

ITEM:
item_id: 0002
item_location: second location
item_description: something else
```

processed_file.txt:

```
first location
second location
```

WANTED_processed_file.txt:

```
['0001', 'first location']
['0002', 'second location']
```

Thank you and apologies for the lengthy post

Comment: Don't open a file at every iteration of the loop please. Use `with` blocks when doing file I/O

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse a multiline blocs from a text file. The robust way would be to process it line by line searching for start of bloc markers and data markers, fill a data structure and then store the data to a file.

If you are sure that your items will always be in the same order, you could use a multiline regex:

```
import re
...
with open('raw_file.txt') as fd:
   text = fd.read()
rx = re.compile(r'ITEM:.*?item_id: ([^\n]*).*?item_location: ([^\n]*)',
                re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
with open('processed_file', 'w') as fd:
    for record in rx.finditer(t):
        print(list(record), file=fd)
```

But beware, it will be less robust than a true parser...

Comment: Had to change `readall` to `read`  but I still get `NameError: name 're' is not defined` and if I change it to some defined variable I get `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'compile'`. What would be the corresponding function for python 3.9?

Comment: @rocky-evasive-dosage: you must import the `re` module (see my edit).